# How get outlook email of Outlook Application ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I want to get only the email with the user is logged in outlook application. I want to check if the mail with which the user has the session started, exists in the database. That allows him to enter into system.

So, I only want to get the email of the current session of Outlook Application.

I hope that you can understand me, thank you.

I'm working with ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

You may consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information. Or just [Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations).

Answer (score 0):

```
inboxFolder = nameSpace.Folders["my-account@myserver.com"].Folders["Unsent mails"];

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem in inboxFolder.Items)
{
    if (mailItem.UnRead) //If mail is unread
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accounts: {0}", mailItem.Body); //read body to console
    }    
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(, what is nameSpace? and what kind of variable is inboxFolder?

Comment: Its part of the office-interop https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268760.aspx